# Change decoration for certain elements in UICalendarView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple calendar app made using UICalendarView. After clicking on certain date in calendar it adds selected date to `var components = [DateComponents]()`.

```
func dateSelection(_ selection: UICalendarSelectionSingleDate, didSelectDate dateComponents: DateComponents?) {
    components.append(dateComponents!)
    calendarView.reloadDecorations(forDateComponents: components, animated: true)
```

Now I want to change decoration for selected components using `decorationFor` method.

```
func calendarView(_ calendarView: UICalendarView, decorationFor dateComponents: DateComponents) -> UICalendarView.Decoration? {
    if components.count == 0 {
        return .default()
    }

    if components.count >= 1 {
        return .customView() {
            let emoji = UILabel()
            emoji.text = ""
            return emoji
        }
    }
    return .default()
}
```

But I don't know how to address `dateComponents` so it can return required decoration only for selected dates. Any ideas?

I made a simple check in case components array is empty, but don't know how to return decorations for certain elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
func calendarView(_ calendarView: UICalendarView, decorationFor dateComponents: DateComponents) -> UICalendarView.Decoration? {
    if components.contains(dateComponents) {
        return .customView() {
            let emoji = UILabel()
            emoji.text = ""
            return emoji
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```